# How to make a Sub Table view in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView displaying a list of domain :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableView.dataSource = mainClass.domainList;
}
```

The domain list is set up like that :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.domainList count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.domainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];

    return cell;
}
```

This works perfectly, it displays each domain in a row of my table view.

Now i would like to add a "Sub TableView" in each cell of my Table View to display a list of documents related to the domain. 
I tried that :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    table.dataSource = [self.domainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.domainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    [cell.contentView addSubView table]

    return cell;
}
```

It doesn't crash but it doesn't work neither. I mean the sublist doesn't appear anywhere.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`datasource` must be a class implementing the protocol `UITableViewDataSource`. It looks like you are setting it to a custom object. Create a separate class with the code you used to implement the first table, then set the sublist as source data. In the objc.io article “[clean table view code](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html)” they explain how to make reusable datasources. Or you can just give it a try on your own.

Consider this code:

```
// ARRAYDATASOURCE.H

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^TableViewCellConfigureBlock)(id cell, id item);

@interface ArrayDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

-(id) init __attribute__((unavailable("disabled, try initWithItems:cellIdentifier:configureCellBlock")));

- (id) initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
      cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
  configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock;

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end


// ARRAYDATASOURCE.M

#import "ArrayDataSource.h"

@interface ArrayDataSource ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cellIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) TableViewCellConfigureBlock configureCellBlock;
@end

@implementation ArrayDataSource

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
     cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
 configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = anItems;
        self.cellIdentifier = aCellIdentifier;
        self.configureCellBlock = [aConfigureCellBlock copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.items[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.configureCellBlock(cell, item);
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes this is currently the case.
    table.dataSource = [self.domainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

the objectAtIndex function return a domain which implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol

Comment: Then you should put breakpoints in the UITableViewDataSource and see if they are being called. Also check that the table view has the correct dimensions, you are not setting a frame on it.